What is special of the transition metals?
The title of a book I am now reading is 'multiplets of transition-metal ions in crystals'.
I am curious about one point. Why transition-metal? What is the point of emphasizing it? It seems to me that the crystal field theory is quite general, and applicable to all elements.

d electrons make for odder behavior with different symmetry and more levels close together.
